# Calling a Method of another class with a lambda expression in python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter, lambda

I am trying to create a little GUI with multiple pages. The First page has a button which raises the second page and changes the label text on the second page. However, I fail to call the method of the second page which is supposed to change the text. Can somebody tell me, why I get the following error when calling the method: `SecondPage.changeLabel()`?

**TypeError: changeLabel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**

UPDATE:

```
    import tkinter as tk


class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (FirstPage, SecondPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(FirstPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, frame_class):
        return self.frames[frame_class]


class FirstPage(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        page = controller.get_page(SecondPage)

        self.buttonFP = tk.Button(self, text="Next Page",
                                  command=lambda : [f for f in [page.changeLabel(),
                                                                controller.show_frame(SecondPage)]])
        self.buttonFP.pack()



class SecondPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Test")

        self.label.pack()


    def changeLabel(self):
        """change text of label"""

        newLabel = "changed"
        self.label.configure(text=newLabel)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you are trying to call the method on the class rather than on the *instance* of the class.

Since your architecture has a controller, you can modify the controller to have a function that returns the instance of a page. You can then use the instance to call methods on that page.

Example:

```
class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    ...
    def get_page(self, frame_class):
        return self.frames[frame_class]
```

Later, you can use this method to get the instance of the page, and use the instance to call the method:

```
page = self.controller.get_page(SecondPage)
page.changeLabel()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For some reason your code works just when I combine creating an instance of the class and callings its method like `controller.get_page(SecondPage).changeLabel() within the lamda function`. Otherwise I am getting a `KeyError: <class '__main__.SecondPage'>` Do you know what could be the reason for that?

Comment: @Max2603: you're probably calling `get_page` before that page has been created.

Comment: I updated my code above with your suggestions. I created the instance within FirstPage Class. What is the standard way of creating the instance of the class?

Comment: @Max2603: Your code does not create the instance within the FirstPage class. The instance is created in the loop, on this line: `frame = F(container, self)`. You shouldn't try getting the page until the user clicks the button. And for that, you shouldn't use `lambda`. Just create a normal function and have the button call that function.